# execCommand heading not working

Tags: javascript, html, rich-text-editor, execcommand

As the title explains, for some reason `document.execCommand('heading', false, 'h1')` (or any other heading size) does not work. However, other commands such as `'bold'`, `'link'`, et cetera, do work.

I am looking at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=document.exe) and it seems to be supported across the board while there are "0 known issues."

Below is the code I am using. Notably, I tried embedding a demo and even creating a codepen, but for some reason none the of the commands work in either.

```
const formatToolClass = document.getElementsByClassName('format-tool')

const preventDefault = (e) => e.preventDefault()

const applyStyle = function(){
  document.designMode = 'on'
  document.execCommand('heading', false, 'h1') // does not work
  document.execCommand('bold', false, null) // will work
  document.designMode = 'off'
}

for (let i = 0; i < formatToolClass.length; i++){
  formatToolClass[i].addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault)
  formatToolClass[i].addEventListener('click', applyStyle)
}
```

**Any idea what is going on??**

P.S. Below is the HTML and CSS in case you want to mess around with it in a browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Is required and cannot be empty.</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">\
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/write.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="controls">
      <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-embolden" data-xcom="bold">Embolden</div>
      <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-italicize" data-xcom="italic">Italicize</div>
      <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-heading" data-xcom="heading">Heading</div> <!---->
      <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-link" data-xcom="createLink">Link</div> <!---->
      <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-list" data-xcom="insertUnorderedList">List</div>
      <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-image" data-xcom="insertImage">Image</div> <!---->
      <div class="controls" id="controls-shortcuts">Shortcuts</div>
      <div class="controls" id="controls-save">Save</div>
      <div class="controls" id="controls-publish">Publish</div>
    </div>
    <div id="user-input" contenteditable="true">
      By portraying me in a sexual way to attendees, this would have opened the door to additional harassment, and added yet another hurdle I’d have to overcome in order to be perceived as a competent professional. The fact that nowhere along the way did ReactiveConf organizers recognize how this gift could actually be harmful, to me, demonstrated a complete lack of empathy for women in tech. That’s not an organization I want to associate myself or my employer, Meteor Development Group (MDG), with.

      Not only is the photo itself problematic, but also the fact that ReactiveConf never asked for my consent. I was never informed that ReactiveConf was planning on altering my photo for the event, nor did I see the superhero picture until after day one of the conference had ended. None of the organizers explicitly asked for my permission to display the picture on the big screen. Had I presented my talk on day 1, I would have been completely blindsided as I walked on stage, which is what happened to a colleague of mine who was also unhappy with his picture.

      Speaking at a conference is already a monumental investment of mental, emotional, and physical effort, right up until the plane ride home. The will to continue investing any more energy into an event whose organizers had showed so little consideration for their speakers vanished as soon as I received the gift. After consulting with trusted members of my team, I decided to withdraw and leave the situation immediately.

      By portraying me in a sexual way to attendees, this would have opened the door to additional harassment, and added yet another hurdle I’d have to overcome in order to be perceived as a competent professional. The fact that nowhere along the way did ReactiveConf organizers recognize how this gift could actually be harmful, to me, demonstrated a complete lack of empathy for women in tech. That’s not an organization I want to associate myself or my employer, Meteor Development Group (MDG), with.
    </div>
    <script src="js/write.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#controls {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:solid red 1px;
}

.controls {
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:solid orange 1px;
}

#user-input {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  padding: 1.25%;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 3vmin;
  color: #000;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:solid black 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are making a wrong assumption. The caniuse site states that `execCommand` is supported without issues, which is correct, **but that doesn't mean that all the commands are supported**. In fact, the [caniuse page](https://caniuse.com/#search=execcommand) has a comment in the Notes section:

> To determine what commands are supported, see `Document.queryCommandSupported()`

And if you check "heading", you'll see it is not supported in Chrome:

```js
console.log(document.queryCommandSupported("heading"))
```

It is not supported on IE either. Firefox states that it supports it, but it may or may not be in the way you expect: instead of applying the heading styles to only the selected text, it applies it to the whole block (works like a "formatBlock" which makes sense as a heading is a block level element and not an inline element as a bold/italics would be).

If that works for you, there's a workaround that is using "formatBlock" as it is supported by Chrome, Firefox and IE:

```js
console.log(document.queryCommandSupported("formatBlock"))
```

In that case, what you would do is setting the formatBlock to the heading you want (looks like an `h1`) and it will work:

```js
const formatToolClass = document.getElementsByClassName('format-tool')

const preventDefault = (e) => e.preventDefault()

const applyStyle = function() {
  document.designMode = 'on'
  document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'h1')
  document.designMode = 'off'
}

for (let i = 0; i < formatToolClass.length; i++) {
  formatToolClass[i].addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault)
  formatToolClass[i].addEventListener('click', applyStyle)
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#controls {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.controls {
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid orange 1px;
}

#user-input {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  padding: 1.25%;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 3vmin;
  color: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="controls">
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-embolden" data-xcom="bold">Embolden</div>
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-italicize" data-xcom="italic">Italicize</div>
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-heading" data-xcom="heading">Heading</div>
  <!---->
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-link" data-xcom="createLink">Link</div>
  <!---->
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-list" data-xcom="insertUnorderedList">List</div>
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-image" data-xcom="insertImage">Image</div>
  <!---->
  <div class="controls" id="controls-shortcuts">Shortcuts</div>
  <div class="controls" id="controls-save">Save</div>
  <div class="controls" id="controls-publish">Publish</div>
</div>
<div id="user-input" contenteditable="true">
  By portraying me in a sexual way to attendees, this would have opened the door to additional harassment, and added yet another hurdle I’d have to overcome in order to be perceived as a competent professional. The fact that nowhere along the way did ReactiveConf
  organizers recognize how this gift could actually be harmful, to me, demonstrated a complete lack of empathy for women in tech. That’s not an organization I want to associate myself or my employer, Meteor Development Group (MDG), with. Not only is the
  photo itself problematic, but also the fact that ReactiveConf never asked for my consent. I was never informed that ReactiveConf was planning on altering my photo for the event, nor did I see the superhero picture until after day one of the conference
  had ended. None of the organizers explicitly asked for my permission to display the picture on the big screen. Had I presented my talk on day 1, I would have been completely blindsided as I walked on stage, which is what happened to a colleague of mine
  who was also unhappy with his picture. Speaking at a conference is already a monumental investment of mental, emotional, and physical effort, right up until the plane ride home. The will to continue investing any more energy into an event whose organizers
  had showed so little consideration for their speakers vanished as soon as I received the gift. After consulting with trusted members of my team, I decided to withdraw and leave the situation immediately. By portraying me in a sexual way to attendees,
  this would have opened the door to additional harassment, and added yet another hurdle I’d have to overcome in order to be perceived as a competent professional. The fact that nowhere along the way did ReactiveConf organizers recognize how this gift
  could actually be harmful, to me, demonstrated a complete lack of empathy for women in tech. That’s not an organization I want to associate myself or my employer, Meteor Development Group (MDG), with.
</div>
```

---

Now, if you want only the text that you selected to be an H1, then you could do a trick: use "insertHTML" to add the tags `<h1>` and `</h1>` surrounding the selected text (it will work on Edge, but not on Internet Explorer). Something like this:

```js
const formatToolClass = document.getElementsByClassName('format-tool')

const preventDefault = (e) => e.preventDefault()

const applyStyle = function() {
  document.designMode = 'on'
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<h1>' + window.getSelection().toString() + '</h1>')
  document.designMode = 'off'
}

for (let i = 0; i < formatToolClass.length; i++) {
  formatToolClass[i].addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault)
  formatToolClass[i].addEventListener('click', applyStyle)
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#controls {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.controls {
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid orange 1px;
}

#user-input {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  padding: 1.25%;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 3vmin;
  color: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="controls">
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-embolden" data-xcom="bold">Embolden</div>
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-italicize" data-xcom="italic">Italicize</div>
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-heading" data-xcom="heading">Heading</div>
  <!---->
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-link" data-xcom="createLink">Link</div>
  <!---->
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-list" data-xcom="insertUnorderedList">List</div>
  <div class="controls format-tool" id="controls-image" data-xcom="insertImage">Image</div>
  <!---->
  <div class="controls" id="controls-shortcuts">Shortcuts</div>
  <div class="controls" id="controls-save">Save</div>
  <div class="controls" id="controls-publish">Publish</div>
</div>
<div id="user-input" contenteditable="true">
  By portraying me in a sexual way to attendees, this would have opened the door to additional harassment, and added yet another hurdle I’d have to overcome in order to be perceived as a competent professional. The fact that nowhere along the way did ReactiveConf
  organizers recognize how this gift could actually be harmful, to me, demonstrated a complete lack of empathy for women in tech. That’s not an organization I want to associate myself or my employer, Meteor Development Group (MDG), with. Not only is the
  photo itself problematic, but also the fact that ReactiveConf never asked for my consent. I was never informed that ReactiveConf was planning on altering my photo for the event, nor did I see the superhero picture until after day one of the conference
  had ended. None of the organizers explicitly asked for my permission to display the picture on the big screen. Had I presented my talk on day 1, I would have been completely blindsided as I walked on stage, which is what happened to a colleague of mine
  who was also unhappy with his picture. Speaking at a conference is already a monumental investment of mental, emotional, and physical effort, right up until the plane ride home. The will to continue investing any more energy into an event whose organizers
  had showed so little consideration for their speakers vanished as soon as I received the gift. After consulting with trusted members of my team, I decided to withdraw and leave the situation immediately. By portraying me in a sexual way to attendees,
  this would have opened the door to additional harassment, and added yet another hurdle I’d have to overcome in order to be perceived as a competent professional. The fact that nowhere along the way did ReactiveConf organizers recognize how this gift
  could actually be harmful, to me, demonstrated a complete lack of empathy for women in tech. That’s not an organization I want to associate myself or my employer, Meteor Development Group (MDG), with.
</div>
```

Comment: Very informative. I only had enough time to skim through it, but I imagine this will get the job done. I do remember reading about the `queryCommandSupported` method, but I must have forgot about it since I have only been able to work on this project for 20 minutes here and 20 minutes there. I will mark this as the answer, when I get a chance to implement it.

Comment: if you select the first or last word, for some reason it removed them from `div#user-input` and places them either before or after :/ how come? also, can you take a look at this other question i just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232304/check-if-selection-contains-link

Comment: Wow! I hadn't noticed that in the second example. That's weird, let me check if I can fix it somehow.

Comment: for some reason `insertHTML` embeds a bunch of useless HTML. if you press enter a couple times, it will embed something like `<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div>` :/

Comment: also, it's funny because making the first and last words don't end up outside of `div#user-input` if you start with an empty `div`